# In which SG1 Season and Episode did Teal'c say 'Medical Operation'?

Tags: episode-identification, stargate-sg1

I am looking for the episode where Teal'c says something like:

'medical operation'

and O'Neill says:

'It's surgical...'

Comment: Hey @Dosco , thanks for editing my question, I didn't know that epsiode ID was a tag!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe this is from the Season 1 finale, titled "[Within the serpent's grasp](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/1.22_%22Within_The_Serpent%27s_Grasp_Part_1%22_Transcript)". This is either episode 22, or it is sometimes numbered as episode 21, depending on whether the double-length opener is counted as one or two episodes.

The exchange runs as:

> Teal'c: If the coordinates are for a Goa'uld world which is not on the
> Abydos cartouche, the Goa'uld will most likely not expect us. I
> believe a medical attack could be successful.
>
> Jack O'Neill: Surgical attack, Teal'c. It's called a surgical attack.

Comment: yes that is it :D

Comment: I think its is episode 21, but I don't know if there was a cancelled one. irt's the last from s1

Comment: It depends on if you count the pilot/opener as one or two episodes. It is sometimes broadcast as two because of schedules.

Comment: hi, I think the pilot is a double episode maybe that's why, anyways your answer is correct just ambigious on the exact number ;)

Comment: @SAJW Yes, it is numbered differently in different sites, so I've added an explanation. The episode title is unambiguous though

Comment: Indeed.  (padding)